# "incompatible type passed in as parameter"

Tags: google-apps-script

I receive this error message:

"incompatible type passed in as parameter"

after my program has been idle for a period(usually after returning from a break but sometimes sooner). 
Are there variables that time-out after a period? And, how can I handle the error better rather than receiving this mysterious error message?

Has anyone experienced this when mistakenly identical Id's on different elements?

For example:

var lbl2=app.createLabel("Test1")
          .setId('idlabel');

var lbl3=app.createLabel("Test2")
          .setId('idlabel');

and then resetting the value with:

app.getElementById("idlabel").setText('changed');

Thank You -JS

Comment: Without any code and better description it is difficult to provide help.

Comment: Hi - I found the error after much very difficult troubleshooting: Google Apps Script cannot reliably parse parameters passed to functions when the parameter is an object. For Example: function projEditNew(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var project = new projectO();
  project['op']='insert';
  var title="New Project";
  /*This causes incompatible type error
  Pass into project properties or other instead
  */
  projEdit(project,app,title);
  return app;
}

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, the original answer below is incorrect...Google Apps Script can successfully pass objects as parameters and this does not cause "Incompatible Type Error Message". -JS

I found the error after much very difficult troubleshooting: Google Apps Script cannot reliably parse parameters passed to functions when the parameter is an object. For Example:

```
function projEditNew(e){ 
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication(); 
var project = new projectO(); 
project['op']='insert';
var title="New Project"; /*This causes incompatible type error Pass into project properties or other instead */ 
projEdit(project,app,title); 
return app; 
}
```

Comment: First, you should have just edited your question, instead of posting an answer, which this isn't. Second, this statement is false, your making mistakes somewhere else in your code. Where is functions `project0` and `projEdit` ?

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu - sorry for the improper format and wrong answer, it was not intentional. I edited my question to try to be more accurate.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu - can you please provide me a better vote on my corrected question so I can regain my privileges to ask questions? Thanks! commet